# Is there a php7 library for geometry calculations (specifically the intersection of two polygons)

Tags: intersection, php-7, mapserver, geos

I want to do an polygon intersection calculation with php, but can't find a library to do it.

I looked at [geophp](https://geophp.net/api.html) but that requires [geos](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos) for intersection calculations and there's no php7 bindings yet for geos.

Neither does it look like there's any php 7 bindings yet for [mapServer](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/issues/5252).

Is there anything else out there? Even something written in php...

Answer (score 0):

A little google searching and I found the following if your looking for a pure php solution.
https://blog.bramp.net/post/2011/11/26/php-polygon-clipper-using-the-sutherland-hodgman-algorithm/

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like this requires one of the polygon's to be a rectangle. Also I don't think it's doing a strict intersection it's just returning all the points from a polygon that appear inside a rectangle.

Comment: I have used a javascript polygon clipper that is very good and fast: https://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/Home%206/ if you wanted to convert it to PHP. It is based on  Angus Johnson's C# Clipper Library which is also linked to.